# Buenas practicas para función def en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, python-3.7, beautifulsoup

Estoy haciendo un script que scrapea con bs4 cierta plataforma, la data generalmente viene con caracteres especiales/raros lo cual me obligo a hace runa funcion replace:

```
def replace(self, string):
    '''Funcion que reemplaza los principales
    caracterer raros (ESTANDARIZADOS!!)
    que presenta la metadata 
    en esta web, no va a reemplazar absolutamente todo
    ya que varia entre elemento html y otro.'''

    if '<img' in string:
        clean_data = string.replace('<img src="', '').replace(
                '">', '').replace('" <="" a="', '')

        return clean_data

    elif '\xa0' in string:
        clean_data = string.replace('\xa0', '')
            
        return clean_data
    
    elif '\nX\n' in string:
        clean_data = string.replace(
            '\nX\n        ', '').replace(
            '    ', '').replace(
            '\n', '')
        
        return clean_data
    
    else:
        return string
```

Mi pregunta es basica, como mejorar este codigo en cuanto a buenas practicas? me refiero a la cantidad de veces que seteo clean_data, y la cantidad de returns, lo cual me hacen ruido. Generalmente se van a ir agregando mas elif para testear si cierto string tiene ese caracter raro, por lo tanto siento que en cierto punto va a ser repetitivo.
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A favor: el código sigue un patrón claro y consistente. Bien estructurado y documentado.

La puedes acortar usando un sólo `return` al final de la función. Queda más claro, además:

```
def replace(self, string):
    '''Funcion que reemplaza los principales
    caracterer raros (ESTANDARIZADOS!!)
    que presenta la metadata 
    en esta web, no va a reemplazar absolutamente todo
    ya que varia entre elemento html y otro.'''

    if '<img' in string:
        clean_data = string.replace('<img src="', '').replace(
            '">', '').replace('" <="" a="', '')
    elif '\xa0' in string:
        clean_data = string.replace('\xa0', '')
    elif '\nX\n' in string:
        clean_data = string.replace(
            '\nX\n        ', '').replace(
            '    ', '').replace(
            '\n', '')
    else:
        clean_data = string
        
    return clean_data
```